# Как можно использовать if вместо тернарного оператора в такой конструкции?

Tags: javascript, if, синтаксис

```js
const returnAmount = (status === 'Accepted') ? undefined : returnAmountRaw - betAmount
```

Как можно использовать if вместо тернарного оператора в такой конструкции?

Comment: И на ваши тоже.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38765194/conditionally-initializing-a-constant-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Вы требуете невозможного. Ваше выражение нельзя переделать в условные блоки: если объявить переменную `const` вне блоков, её значение нельзя будет изменить в блоках. Если её определять внутри условных блоков, она не будет видна вне их и потеряет свой смысл.

Comment: На самом деле возможно :)

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду ответ по вашей ссылке, то там ведь меняются условия. Мы уже не определяем `const` в блоках, мы делаем это или при помощи функции, или при помощи промежуточной `let`.

Comment: let a ... const q = a

Comment: Но сделать то можно..

Comment: Ну, тогда нужно уточнять задание — или нам нужно условно определить const (это практический вопрос и это можно), или, как автор просит, переделать тернарное выражение в условные блоки с тем же типом переменной (это скорее академический вопрос и нельзя).

Comment: Ну смотря как постараться.

Answer (score 3):

В satge 0 есть предложение про [do expressions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-do-expressions), с которым получится так:

```
const returnAmount = do {
  if (status !== 'Accepted') returnAmountRaw - betAmount
}
```

Babel его уже поддерживает при включении соответствующего флага, а [при компиляции получается](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBATgUygVzmAggWxMssC8MAJiDAN4BQMMAlgGYwAU0AhihDAIT6EDk6wYAgAOUBEV4BKeElQZsuKACUWAdxgBaGACMkWHHgoBfIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.12.12&externalPlugins=) почти исходная конструкция:

```
"use strict";

const returnAmount = status !== 'Accepted' ? returnAmountRaw - betAmount : void 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Формально это тоже ответ, хотя лучше не городить такое:

```
const returnAmount = (() => {
  if (status !== 'Accepted') return returnAmountRaw - betAmount
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

Только с заменой `const` на `let`:

```
let returnAmount
if (status !== 'Accepted') returnAmount = returnAmountRaw - betAmount
```